# For /F doing the loop operations only for one string segment

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

```
@echo off
set files=InstallSlinger27.bat:Stash.txt

for /F "delims=:" %%i IN ("%files%") DO (
  ECHO %%i
  if exist %%i (
    echo EXIST
  ) else (
    echo DO NOT EXIST
  )
)
```

I expect the batch file to check if the file InstallSlinger27.bat exists and then check if the file Stash.txt exists.

However, the output is

```
InstallSlinger27.bat
EXIST
```

It does not do the verification for the second file.

I tried some things, and I did loops in the past that where working. I don't want to do checks for %%i then %%j, because the files list could grow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set files=InstallSlinger27.bat:Stash.txt

FOR %%a IN ("%files::=","%") DO (
 IF EXIST %%a (ECHO %%a exists) else (ECHO %%a missing)
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Although I'd suggest you re-think your choice of separator since `:` can occur within a full filename.

Comment: I am having hard time to understand `("%files::=","%")` part can you explain a bit ? What does `,` do ?

Comment: @JohnDOE Substitutes `","` for `:` then surround the whole string with `"`, hence `s1:s2` becomes `" s1 "," s2 "` which is then parsed as a series of quoted strings separated by commas. No doubt spaces would operate just as well in place of commas.

Comment: I'd try using pipe `|` as a separator since comma is also a valid filename character.